# How I can replace all file content with a specified text?

Tags: notepad++

How I can replace all file content with a specified text?

I want to replace all content from (patterns.ini) file with this:

> [Subscription filters]
>  swf
>  css
>  ico
>  jpg
>  gif
>   iframe
>  php
>  png
>  js

How I can do this ?
Yours truly

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the text you want to insert in the file.
2. Open the file `patterns.ini` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the text you copied earlier and save.